# Which value will gettimeofday () return when the system's RTC has not yet been set to the current time?

Tags: gettimeofday

It's about an all-fresh system without NTP or any other external time signal source, whose real-time clock hasn't even been set yet manually. When I query it by using

```c
int gettimeofday (struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
```

…which return value resp. `timeval` struct will I get then? A random one, one representing the "epoch" (1970-01-01), or some kind of error?